# Booting and keyboard issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, keyboard, windows-10

My laptop suffered some water damage which made half of the keyboard unusable. So I switched to a Bluetooth one and it works fine.

The problem is that I have dual boot (ubuntu + win10) with Ubuntu set as primary/first on the list so I have to use arrow keys from the damaged keyboard to navigate to windows (BT one doesn't work in GRUB). Today more keyboard stopped responding, including the arrow keys. So I tried through Ctrl+N and it thankfully worked.

My main issue is that now I'd like to change boot order so I don't have to do a keyboard parkour every time I want to turn on my laptop, however I'd have to do that from Ubuntu... to which I can't even log into because the password I had set before the water accident includes letters that do not work on the damaged keyboard. The BT one isn't connected in Ubuntu (I guess) so it doesn't work... I've tried changing order through Windows but it doesn't even detect there's anything to boot. Is there a way out of this (beside buying a new laptop/not turning it off at all)?

TL;DR:

- wants to change order in GRUB
- has to probably do it from Ubuntu
- can't log into Ubuntu bc of keyboard issues

Comment: Why not buy a cheap USB keyboard?

Comment: technically this keyboard can be either on BT or USB but I don't know if this will solve the issue? Plus I need USB ports for other things I use, that's why I use it through BT

Comment: OK well you say the BT keyboard does not work as you need, in grub. But you want to use it in BT mode? So I know I can not help you.

Comment: I can switch it to USB for booting purposes/grub if that's going to help, it's just that once windows is up and running I need that USB port for something else.

Comment: Take your laptop somewhere where there is a USB keyboard and try switching your  laptop to USB for booting purposes before you buy a USB keyboard.